# StreamCorruptedException during the creation of a customizable java client

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, client, objectinputstream

I am attempting to write a simple but customizable client with Java, but I get a bizarre exception in the execution of the tests, more specifically the creation of the input stream. The basic idea is this:

```
public class Client {

    private String ipServer;
    private int portNumber;
    private Socket socket;

    /** A flag value that indicates whenever {@code this} {@link Client} is connected to a <i>server</i>.   */
    private boolean clientIsActive = false;
    /** It will acquire data sent from the <i>server</i> to the <i>client</i>.  */
    private ObjectInputStream streamIn = null;
    /** It will send data from the <i>client</i> to the <i>server</i>.  */
    private ObjectOutputStream streamOut = null;

    /** The instructions {@code this} {@link Client} will follow to communicate with the <i>server</i>.     */
    private Consumer<Client> communicationProtocol = null;

    public Client(String ipServer, int portNumber, Consumer<Client> communicationProtocol) {
        this.ipServer = ipServer;
        this.portNumber = portNumber;
        this.communicationProtocol = communicationProtocol;
    }

}
```

Once created, the `Client` class doesn't immediately connect to the server. First it is needed to execute the `openConnection()` method: its goal is to create the socket, open the Streams and starts executing the instructions.

```
    public void openConnection() {
        // Activates the socket and streams
        try {   this.socket = new Socket(ipServer, portNumber);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {          e.printStackTrace();        } 
              catch (IOException e) {                   e.printStackTrace();        }
        try {   this.streamIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream()); // THIS LINE CAUSES EXCEPTION ! ! ! 
            } catch (IOException e) {                   e.printStackTrace();        }
        try {   this.streamOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {                   e.printStackTrace();        }

        this.clientIsActive = true;
        // Starts communicating according to the specified communication protocol
        this.communicationProtocol.accept(this);
    }
```

To test whenever the code works, I am using the following test. The first method creates the following instructions:

1. The client waits for the first message from the server and uses it accoding to the `updateManager`, i.e. the message instructions.
2. The first message is then used by the `updateManager`, i.e. the message instructions. In my test, this will be a simple "print the received String to console".
3. If it is expected for the server to send more than one update, and if the update received is not the `exitSignal`, the client repeats the points 1. and 2. until the `exitSignal` is transmitted.
4. When the client receives the `exitSignal`, it closes the connection.

```
public static <T> Consumer<Client> serverSendsUpdatesToClients(Consumer<T> updateManager, T exitSignal, boolean sendsSingleUpdate){
        return (Client client) -> {
            T currentUpdate;

            currentUpdate = client.receiveMessage();
            updateManager.accept(currentUpdate);

            if( currentUpdate != exitSignal && !sendsSingleUpdate )
                do  {
                    currentUpdate = client.receiveMessage();
                    updateManager.accept(currentUpdate);
                    } while( currentUpdate != exitSignal );
            client.closeConnection();
            };
    }
```

The second method is a main that connects the client to the NIST server. The specific port used is reserved to a time request service.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Consumer<String> stringManager = (String s) -> {    System.out.println(s);  };
        Consumer<Client> instructions;

        Client client = null;

        instructions = CCPs.serverSendsUpdatesToClients(stringManager, "…", true);
        client = new Client("time.nist.gov",        13, instructions);

        client.openConnection();
    }
```

The output I expect is something like:

```
*58068 17-11-11 10:26:13 00 0 0 152.5 UTC(NIST) *
```

What I get instead is:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 0A353838
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at client.Client.openConnection(Client.java:86)
    at test.TestClient.main(TestClient.java:26)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at client.Client.receiveMessage(Client.java:126)
    at client.CCPs.lambda$0(CCPs.java:33)
    at client.Client.openConnection(Client.java:93)
    at test.TestClient.main(TestClient.java:26)
```

The exception relates to the input stream, which is not created. What is the problem?

Comment: The peer has written something the connection that isn't an `ObjectOutputStream` header. What makes you think it is using Serialization at all?

Comment: NB There is no [tag:socketexception] here. Read the stack trace.